# Get age from timestamp

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with timestamp of BirthDate = 2001-10-10 11:01:04.343
How can I get an actual age?

I tried like that:

`i.loc[0, "BirthDate"] = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize() - i.loc[0, "BirthDate"].normalize()`

output is: 7248 days 00:00:00

but is there any better method which give me just output 19 years?

If i use:

`(i.loc[0, "BirthDate"] = pd.to_datetime('today').normalize() - i.loc[0, "BirthDate"].normalize())/365`

the output is:
19 days 20:34:50:958904109 and it is type <class 'pandas.timedeltas.Timedelta>

Comment: grab the days and divide it by 365 either round value or typecast the value to int according to your need

Comment: Be aware of leap years if dividing the total number of days by a fixed number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `timedelta` result is wrong because you are dividing by 365 where you shouldn't. It actually means 19.86 years.

In some more detail, you are taking a value which is in years, and dividing it with 365; so now you have a result which shows 1/365 of the input duration.  The proper way to get the result in years is to divide by another `timedelta`.

```
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> t = timedelta(days=7248)
>>> 7248/365.0
19.85753424657534
>>> print(t)
7248 days, 0:00:00
>>> t/timedelta(days=365)
19.85753424657534
>>> # years
```

How exactly to represent a year is not completely well-defined.  You could use `timedelta(days=365.2425)` for the arithmetically correct length of a year, but then of course that produces odd results if you try to convert that back to a resolution where hours and minutes are important.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the last part of the timestamp and then the following python code can be applied:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date

def calculate_age(born):
    born = datetime.strptime(born, "%d/%m/%Y").date()
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

df['Age'] = df['Date of birth'].apply(calculate_age)
print(df)
```